# Why doesn't XCode auto-prompt/complete swift ENum cases?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, enums

I don't overly care about the inconvenience of the lack of XCode code-completion but rather I am concerned that it suggests I am not using ENums correctly, despite my research and ongoing self-training suggesting I am...

In the following simplified example, how come XCode doesn't prompt me for the available ENum Cases after I type the .? Is this not exactly the sort of simple/constrained data that I should be using an ENum for?

(Note: Assume the code is all in the same simple file).

```
enum Fur: String {
  case None, Curly, Fluffy
}

class Animal {
  let coat: Fur
}
```

Then typing in XCode...

```
var hound = Animal(coat: Fur. <- Expected auto-complete
```

Being fairly new to Swift OOP (Classes, Protocols, Structs and ENums), I'm concerned that XCode not helping me with this fairly obvious completion (and the benefits of more accurate code it brings) suggests I'm not using ENums correctly?

Comment: Works for me... (but your class does not compile).

Comment: Thanks both - and yes my example was simplified for conciseness (so wouldn't compile). Thanks @originaluser2... you're right that it is the same scenario as the custom initialiser question. I did search before posting but I suspect my newbie terminology didn't throw up that question. The fact that a known type does auto-complete in abbreviated form (typing `.Cur` in my example) seems of limited value as it still requires me to know the available Cases.